# Is it possible to call the bit.ly API with VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, bit.ly

How do I reach the `bit.ly` API with VB.net 2010—is it even possible? How?

Comment: VB.NET is it, with Vistual Basic 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was interested myself to see how it works, this might get you started:

```
Option Infer On

Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim wc = New WebClient()
        Dim login = "your_login"
        Dim apiKey = "your_apikey"
        Dim longUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427104/vb-is-there-any-possibility-to-call-the-bit-ly-api")
        Dim request = String.Format("http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login={0}&apiKey={1}&longUrl={2}&format=txt", login, apiKey, longUrl)
        Dim result = wc.DownloadString(request)
    End Sub

End Module
```

The API documentation can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 examples where they use bit.ly to shorten url's. Is this what you're looking for?

- http://www.emadibrahim.com/2009/05/07/shortening-urls-with-bitlys-api-in-net
- http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/09/how-to-use-bitly-api-to-shorten-url-in.html